# Intel Wireless AC 7260 with Asus laptop N550JK - Bluetooth doesn't see any wireless devices

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, bluetooth, asus-laptop

I changed WLAN card on my laptop. I had Qualcomm Atheros AR 3012 for Bluetooth / Atheros 9485WB-EG for Wi-Fi, now I have Intel AC 7260. After changing, I started my laptop and WLAN drivers were immediately installed by the operating system, also the drivers for Bluetooth were installed.

Wi-Fi worked well immediately, Bluetooth also seemed to work, but not quite: When I try to search for the other Bluetooth devices, not all devices are found. For example, I have Bluetooth on my phone turned on (Honor Play) and my computer has found that my phone is ready for pairing, but my wireless headphones (Sony MDR ZX 330 BT) does not want to appear in the wirelless devices list. My headphones just will not be listed there. And I also can connect to my computer from my smartphone and vice versa. On youtube I have also found a video in which a man install the same wlan module in the same laptop and it went without problems with WLAN and Bluetooth.

What have I already done:

1. I have manually downloaded and installed the latest drivers from the Intel website. WLAN module and bluetooth were detected, but the problem with Bluetooth remained.
2. I checked if bluetooth services are running. Yes, they are running! [see attachments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18Ry7.jpg)
3. I have tried to mask PIN No. 51 on the wireless module. That did not work. The problem remained.

My OS is Windows 10, my laptop is Asus N550JK. My wireless headset is Sony MDR-ZK330BT.

Does somebody have any idea, what else could I do in order to get my Bluetooth on Intel AC 7260 to work properly?

**UPDATE** I added an attachment with the driver version. [Wi-Fi driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0egN.jpg) [Bluetooth driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akmXg.jpg) . 
You can see that the driver for Bluetooth is a bit old (from the year 2015), but that's just because I manually installed the older driver. 
I have already tried to install the newer driver (from the current year), but that did not help me, the problem remained.

Comment: I have that card on my Lenovo laptop. The latest Intel driver makes it an 8260 card. Did that happen? Have you got the latest BIOS installed?

Comment: The headphones might have been connected to your phone already (or another device) and have thus turned off pairing mode - this happens to my bluetooth headphones anyway. Pairing mode is indicated by red/blue flashing on mine and thats how I know I should be seeing it on the list of devices

Comment: @John No, after drivers installing it was a 7260 card. I doesn't have the latest BIOS, but I updated my BIOS in 2017.

Comment: @QuickishFM ehm, I'm sure the pairing mode is on. The light flashes (red / blue).